# SpringBoot base packages are not scanning

Tags: java, spring-boot

Following is my project structure.

[image: project structure]

My main class is DemoApplication.java which has the "scan base packages."

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.demo.ex"})
public class DemoApplication{   
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

This was working fine until I replace my JPA Repository with Mongo repository.

My BookRepository looks like following.

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<Book, String>{  
   public Book findOneById(String id);
}
```

My BookServiceImpl looks similar to following.

```
@Service("bookService")
  public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService{  
  @Autowired
  BookRepository bookRepository;
 ....... 
}
```

Now the application fails to start and complains as below.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field bookRepository in com.demo.ex.service.BookServiceImpl required a bean of 
type 'com.demo.ex.repository.BookRepository' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.demo.ex.repository.BookRepository' in 
your configuration.
```

I do not want to use @EnableMongoRepositories annotation as it asks me to create a mongo-template.

What would be the best way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to use @EnableMongoRepositories annotation as it asks me to create a mongo-template.

You need that annotation, but if you define the Mongo connection settings in your application.properties (or equivalent) Spring will create the template for you.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

See the MONGODB (MongoProperties) section.

More info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb